# Is it possible to use Magento 2.4 with Elasticsearch 6?

Tags: search, server-setup, elasticsearch, magento2.4

I know that Elasticsearch 6 is deprecated and we're supposed to use 7.6 or above, but I just went through the process of updating, only to find that my host (Cloudways) doesn't provide access to Elasticsearch 7 (yet), and don't provide root access, so I can't add it myself.

Is there a way to do some sort of workaround to make it work for a couple of weeks, or do I have to just stash my work on its current branch, and revisit this upgrade in a few weeks?

Thanks

Comment: have you actually tried it? The wording from the docs says “you can use other versions at your discretion” ...

Comment: I have it running at 6.5, and while it works on categories, it doesn't work on products.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the link from [Magento Devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html).

It  clearly mention that it will not working with the Elastic Search 6.

Check the Image also.

[image]

Hope answer helps you.

Happy Coding.

Comment: Yes, I saw that. I made it very clear in my question that I saw that, and asked if there was a workaround.